# Embbeding FLV video file into an HTML page without losing transparency

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a free and working way to embed an Flv video with a transparent background on my html5 page.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.

To get useful help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

See more from here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask